# Why use a molten dataframe instead of a cast dataframe (or vice versa)

Tags: r, dataframe

We were going over dataframes in my statistics class today, and my instructor told us about a 'molten' type and a 'cast' type.  I understand what the differences are and how to convert between the two - but why would I do this?  What, if anything, makes one of them more/less useful than the other? Are there specific cases where one would be preferable to the other?

My instructor told us that "we would know when we needed to use one or the other just by looking at it"... But I have no idea what I'm even looking for.  A google search for "molten vs cast in R" gave me all sorts of helpful links for if I needed to know how to do it, but not why one is preferred to the other.

Comment: Most modeling functions in R (`lm`, `glm`, etc) will require that your data be in "long" rather than "wide" form.

Comment: See http://vita.had.co.nz/papers/tidy-data.html for my answer

Answer (score 1):

In addition to modeling, I have found that *long* datasets can be helpful with plotting varying levels.  When I am doing analysis and typically need data as 1 row per observation, I re-work my data to be *wide.*

In the end, there isn't a precise answer, but the beauty of packages like `reshape2` is that you beat your data into whatever form you need.